# Is it true that set of all irrational and algebraic numbers ($\mathbb{Q}^c\cap algebraic$) is dense in real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis

> Is it true that the set of all irrational and algebraic numbers ($\mathbb Q^c\cap algebraic$) is dense in real numbers?

Actually I was trying to show the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}2\ \ ,\textrm{if x is irrational and algebraic}\\
0\ \ , \textrm{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
is discontinuous everywhere in $\mathbb R.$ It's easy to show at $x$ where $x\in \mathbb Q^c\cap algebraic.$ But for the points $x$ when $x\in \mathbb Q^c\setminus algebraic$ we need a sequence from irrational and algebraic points set converging to $x$. So for the later one I was trying to show whether set of  irrational and algebraic numbers is dense in $\mathbb R$ or not.

Thank you. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it is dense. Already $\{\sqrt 2+r:r\in\mathbb Q\}$ is dense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because $\left\{q\sqrt2\,\middle|\,q\in\mathbb Q\setminus\{0\}\right\}$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.